# ETL Steps and Performance Guide

Tags: pentaho, etl

I am new to ETL and BI intelligence. I want to learn and work on Pentaho Spoon tool for ETL. I have searched a lot for a tutorial/blog or guide which should be an excellent and easy for a nascent user. i want this tutorial consisting of following things.

**i.** Which steps should be used?

**ii.** Where should we use any step?

**iii.** Which steps should be skipped and why?

**iv.** How to maintain the performance?

The performance is the main issue for me and i want to make a brilliant KTR's in the sense of time and memory.

**Note:** For me Stackoverflow is the best platform to ask such type of question's from an intelligent and wise peoples.

Comment: Despite your kind note at the end your question is off-topic here and it its current form I guess anywhere else in the SE network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Kettle cookbook ( Proper book, available on amazon ) it has all of this.  This is far too much to answer in a single tutorial or q&a site!

Comment: thanx for referring a book.

Answer (score 1):

The books "Pentaho Solutions" and "Pentaho Kettle Solutions" of Roland Bouman, Jos van Dongen and Matt Casters are recommended too. Further, the first book works with MySQL if it can be useful for you.
I've also read  "Pentaho 3.2 Data Integration", because although it is about an old version, it was quite useful to start and understand how to use some transformations or do some tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This questions seems let research,
butt still you can use Pentaho Data Integration Steps documentation where by going through each step you will get all answer for your question.

[Pentaho Data Integration Steps](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+Steps)